# js memory organization - closures versus objects?

Tags: javascript, performance, object, closures

When I develop in JS, I'm frequently faced with the choice between capturing variables with an inner function (closure) and using an object.

Inner function:

```
var x = ...;
var f = function() {
    // use x here
}
```

Object:

```
obj.x = ...;
obj.f = function() {
    // use x here
}
```

The inner function approach "feels" more natural, but I was wondering - are there performance implications to worry about doing it one way or another, and what is the most idiomatic way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: So `x`, `f` and `obj` would be in some local scope? Please declare that. If not, this question would just be about namespacing. Also, how do you access the `x` in the second variant?

Comment: Micro-optimizations are virtually never worth worrying about. If the **only** concern or difference between two methods is memory micro-management, then you should just use whichever method you prefer. To me, there are usually clearly delineated reasons to use a closure vs. placing properties on an object. Memory is never a factor for me in deciding which approach to use since you don't really manage memory in javascript the way you may in other languages.

Comment: This article may be of interest: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: If you use a closure, you are restricted by scope so you might end up with many closures at the top level scope and all functions as descendents of that scope. With the object approach, you can more easily access values that are set in other scopes which should improve moudlarity of code. Of course there is no one approach that suits every case. In any reasonably complex application you will very likely use a combination of both approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an era where an average PC has 8GB of RAM, memory use by closures vs object properties seems irrelevant. In any case, it is extremely unlikely in a non–trivial application that it will make sense to use only use closures or only property values.

If you have a code module, it makes sense to use closures for variables that are only used internally by methods of that module. It also makes sense to use properties for values that need to be shared across modules without needing to use getters and setters (e.g. where you want to use `obj.property` rather than `obj.getProperty()`).

Also, property access is much more efficient than using a function to retrieve a value, but getters and setters can provide significant functionality (e.g. value validation and integrity checking) over simply reading or assigning a value.

As always, use what suits your application according to whatever criteria seem appropriate (speed, code maintainability, robustness, cross browser support, etc.).

Comment: I pretty much figured there wouldn't be a large performance impact for most applications. Thanks for outlining use cases of each. It sounds like in general there is no consensus on one being better or worse, just complimentary.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the available of RAM as you will not just get it all for your tab like that. In Chrome
you have 1gb limit for example. It has to do with GC pressure and the more memory you use the slower you get. You will
not be able to do server side apps or any javascript rich (games, editors, video stuff, not forums or CRUD) apps like this. The claims about method calls are also pretty much wrong
because you can easily write code in a way that invites function inlining for such cases.

Comment: @Esailija—the point is that given the amount of RAM available, the difference in memory use between closures and object properties is irrelevant for most purposes. What do you mean by "like this"? Are you talking about function inlining at the code or compiler level? Can inlining be used as a general strategy for getters and setters as access to all shared data (i.e. both within and across modules)?

Comment: @RobG "like this" means the way you see people sometimes make their classes by putting the methods inside the constructor. By inlining I mean the inlining optimization done automatically by modern engines whenever possible. The specifics depend on the engine, here are some limitations for [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/hydrogen.cc#L7874) and for SpiderMonkey [here](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/master/js/src/jsanalyze.cpp#L259),
[and here](https://github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/blob/master/js/src/ion/IonBuilder.cpp#L255)

Comment: Here's what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/LG8rB/

Answer (score 1):

Well in fact you allocate extra object in the second case, otherwise they look the same to me.

Functions are first class objects in JS and it's easy to forget that anytime you see `function(){}` that
allocates a new function object which is relatively fat. You could think of it as seeing `new Function()` being called
if that makes the object allocation more obvious to you.

This is only harmful when you have a "constructor" that defines functions inside it and returns an object pointing to those functions.
Each of those functions is a separate object created on top of the object you are creating from the constructor. The functions
will easily take 10-100x more memory than the object and its data itself, depending on the data and amount of methods of course.

If you are writing an application it's easy to consider whether you will ever have to worry about it. If you know
your application will never create many objects at all then the waste of memory isn't so bad in the bigger picture. If you are
writing a general purpose library etc, please don't make these assumptions for application developers whose needs you cannot
predict.